# Cost of Branching SVN vs GIT

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Comparing SVN with GIT,

What's the relative cost comparison of creating a branch of a folder with 100 files (Just an example) between the two?
Which of these have a cheaper cost?

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of how many files, creating a branch is pretty much instantaneous in both systems. It's just creating a reference to a particular revision number.

Comment: @Chris Subversion makes "cheap copies" not copies. In SVN, a branch is just a link to the main tree. SVN only makes a copy when it cannot do away without a link. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html

Answer (score 3):

In such case Subversion will create a "symlink" to the folder.

Copying / tagging / branching in Apache Subversion is instantaneous and cheap. Let me quote [SVNBook | Using Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html):

> **Cheap Copies**
>
> **Subversion's repository has a special design. When you copy a
> directory, you don't need to worry about the repository growing
> huge—Subversion doesn't actually duplicate any data. Instead, it
> creates a new directory entry that points to an existing tree.** If
> you're an experienced Unix user, you'll recognize this as the same
> concept behind a hard link. As further changes are made to files and
> directories beneath the copied directory, Subversion continues to
> employ this hard link concept where it can. It duplicates data only
> when it is necessary to disambiguate different versions of objects.
>
> This is why you'll often hear Subversion users talk about “cheap
> copies.” It doesn't matter how large the directory is—it takes a very
> tiny, constant amount of time and space to make a copy of it. In fact,
> this feature is the basis of how commits work in Subversion: each
> revision is a “cheap copy” of the previous revision, with a few items
> lazily changed within. (To read more about this, visit Subversion's
> web site and read about the “bubble up” method in Subversion's design
> documents.)
>
> Of course, these internal mechanics of copying and sharing data are
> hidden from the user, who simply sees copies of trees. The main point
> here is that copies are cheap, both in time and in space. If you
> create a branch entirely within the repository (by running svn copy
> URL1 URL2), it's a quick, constant-time operation. Make branches as
> often as you want.

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/)!

Comment: I read that Book before posting this. It doesn't asnwer my question. Cost difference between SVN & GIT.

Answer (score 2):

What Cost metric are you referring to exactly?
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/02/24/branching-strategies-the-cost-of-branching-and-merging/

Here is a brief breakdown on the differences between SVN and GIT.
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-git-and-svn/

Here is a link here on SO comparing the SVN 1.8 branching/merging to GIT.
[How is SVN v 1.8 branching / merging compared to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333088/how-is-svn-v-1-8-branching-merging-compared-to-git)

Finally, here is SVNs comments on what a branch actually is (and what it is not):
"Subversion's repository has a special design. When you copy a directory, you don't need to worry about the repository growing huge—Subversion doesn't actually duplicate any data. Instead, it creates a new directory entry that points to an existing tree. If you're an experienced Unix user, you'll recognize this as the same concept behind a hard link."
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.using.html

Comment: I've read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html before posting this. I'm just trying to compare the cost between the two. I went through the other links as well. All of them talk about GIT vs SVN but none of the resources talk about the actual cost difference between the two systems. (Somehow quantifying the cost). It may actually be impossible to quantify but that needs to be proven too.

Comment: Since you are comparing Distributed vs Centralized control systems, you are kinda comparing apples to oranges in some regards.  I will agree that drive space and time to create are faster for GIT, since it only uses pointers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766283/how-does-git-handle-branches-compared-to-svn).

Comment: I'm not attempting to compare all of GIT vs SVN. My question is limited to "cost of branching".